# operator< overloading for std::set

Tags: c++, stl

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

class widget
{
public:
    widget(unsigned id) :
        m_id(id)
    {
    };

    ~widget(){};

    unsigned id(){ return m_id; };
    bool active(){ return m_active; };
    void set_active(bool active){ m_active = active; };

    friend bool operator<(const widget& lhs, const widget& rhs);

    bool operator<(const widget& rhs)
    {
        return m_id < rhs.m_id;
    }

private:
    unsigned m_id;
    bool m_active{false};
};

bool operator<(const widget& lhs, const widget& rhs)
{
    return lhs.m_id < rhs.m_id;
}

int main()
{  
    std::set<widget> widgets;

    widget foo(5);
    widget bar(2);

    widgets.insert(foo);
    widgets.insert(bar);

    for(const auto& hi : widgets)
        std::cout << hi.id() << std::endl;
}
```

On compiling I get the error:
`passing 'const widget' as 'this' argument of 'unsigned int widget::id()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

And I don't understand whats happening. Am I doing the operator overloading wrong? Also, do I need the operator< as a member function with one parameter and as a free function with two parameters?

Comment: bool operator<(const widget& rhs) ---> replace this with bool operator<(const widget& rhs) const and id()--> id() const{}

Comment: You don't need both the member and free function. You *do* need to make the member function `const`

Comment: So I only need a member function with only one parameter. It's working now, thanks guys!

Comment: Yes you just need to overload the operator < for the class Widget. You need to make the operator< overloading function const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `const` qualifier to your function `id`:

```
 unsigned id() const { return m_id; }
```

The reason is that in your loop, you iterate over your `widgets` set using a `const` reference - calling a non-const member function on this is forbidden.